# Generate random coordinates that are farther than 50 units but shorter than 250 units from center

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to specify a range that is greater than 50 units from a center but shorter than 250 units from the center. Currently I have it like so

```
obstacles.append((random.randint(-250, 250), random.randint(-250, 250)))
```

but that specifies ranges less than 50 units from the center and I don't know how to exclude specific ranges. Because it is inside a circle I need both positive and negative values.

Comment: `random.randint(50,250) * random.choice((1, -1))` perhaps?

Comment: That worked I believe, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider generating a random angle from 0 to 2*pi radian (360 degrees) and a random radium from 50 to 250, then convert to Cartesian coordinates.

```py
import random
from math import pi, sin, cos

def gen_coords(r_min=50, r_max=250):
    r = random.randint(r_min, r_max)
    theta = 2 * pi * random.random()
    x = r * cos(theta)
    y = r * sin(theta)
    return round(x), round(y)

obstacles.append(gen_coords())
```

Comment: Rounding is probably going to introduce some significant error in the process. Just return `x` and `y` as they are, and let the consumer decide if integer values are necessary. Consider the case where `r_max=1`; *any* values are going to be rounded down to the 0.

Comment: That is how I originally had it, but since he was talking about "units" instead of absolute distance, I figured he wanted to have pixelated numbers

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way keeping with `random.randint` and paying homage to our friend Pythagoras:

```
import random
import math

limit = random.randint(50, 250)
x = random.randint(-250,250)
y_limit = int(math.sqrt(abs(limit * limit - x * x)))
y = random.randint(-1 * y_limit, y_limit)

obstacles.append((x, y))

print('x: {0}, y: {1}, len: {2}'.format(x, y, int(math.sqrt(x * x + y * y))))
```

Answer (score 0):

James' answer is great if you do not mind frequencies with a greater weight towards the middle of the constraints. If you want uniform randomness across all possible points, you might find the following code to be helpful:

```
import math
import random


def random_int(min_from_center, max_from_center):
    return _constrained_random(min_from_center, max_from_center, random.randint)


def random_float(min_from_center, max_from_center):
    return _constrained_random(min_from_center, max_from_center, random.uniform)


def _constrained_random(min_from_center, max_from_center, method):
    while True:
        x = method(-max_from_center, +max_from_center)
        y = method(-max_from_center, +max_from_center)
        if min_from_center <= math.hypot(x, y) <= max_from_center:
            return x, y
```

The first two functions allow you to decide what data type you want the coordinates to have. The third function ensures that the created points have no bias in their position and are uniformly distributed.